NumericUpDown Control input doesn't appear after losing focus but value stays the old value
During the using of NumericUpDown control in Framework 4.8 version I tent to delete the value inside NumericUpDown control. After leaving the value deleted and empty, the value stays the last input value that I think it should have been reset to 0. I try to refresh, update and validate the control and child controls of NumericUpDown which are UpDownEdit and UpDownButtons but the value doesn't appear in the UI. How do I make the UI to show the value when control loses focus.
Image Explanation Link
I erased the value in control and expected it to be equal to 0 atleast when I lose focus.
UI refresh eventhandler on losing focus:
private void numericUpDown3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown3.Refresh();
        numericUpDown3.Update();
        numericUpDown3.Validate();

        numericUpDown3.Controls[0].Refresh();
        numericUpDown3.Controls[0].Update();

        numericUpDown3.Controls[1].Refresh();
        numericUpDown3.Controls[1].Update();            
    }


Please add Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@SuryatejaKONDLA This is a UI issue. I explained it in the image on the link. In addition I added the refresh code on control.

"I erased the value in control and expected it to be equal to 0". Not sure why you would expect that totally unjustified thing to happen.

@jmcilhinney I think the value shouldn't be equal to the old value atleast. It is misleading that old value is still there.

numericUpDown3.Value = 0; do the trick. Isn't it?

Why shouldn't it be equal to the old value? Blank text is not a number at all so why should the value change to something else? The Value property is not nullable so it has to be a number. Zero is a number, just like any other. It's not no value. You're just making unjustified assumptions.

@jmcilhinney The issue is not that it can be nullable or the value can't be empty. The UI doesn't show the real value when it loses focus. If it is the old value, the UI should refresh itself to the old or any value that it should indicate. Check the image for explanation.

@AlexanderPetrov It doesn't show it on the UI when I do it. The UI seems to be a null or valueless control. That the first thing I tried. Thanks for the offer.
